# DELETE Request in Android doesn't connect to server

Tags: java, android

So my question is how can I create a DELETE Request to an URL in Android Studio Java. I already have an Async Task which GET json from URL. So my question now is how can I create a DELETE request

EDIT:

So right now I got this code:

```
   int pos = arrlist.get(info.position).getId();
                    URL_DELETE = "http://testserver/test/tesst.php?id=" + pos + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(URL_DELETE);
                        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
                        httpCon.setRequestProperty(
                                "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
                        httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

To understand the content of the given URL should be deleted. But if I run the code nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [`connect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection#connect()) on the `HttpURLConnection`.  Right now you're not actually making a connection to the server.

Based on your comments on the other answer, you're also trying to run this code on the main (UI) thread - you'll need to change your code to [run on a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OkHttp:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().delete().url(url).build();
Response rawResponse = null;
try {
      rawResponse = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}

String responseAsString = rawResponse.body().string();
```

Comment: how or where do I call request?

Comment: Copy paste the snippet, url is either an HttpUrl or a string and your response is going to be in responseAsString. Let me know if you have further issues...

Comment: My app crash with your method with the exception     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException